# Bootstrap Multiselect filtering values based on another dropdown

Tags: bootstrap-multiselect

I'm working on cascading the multi-select based on the values of the data-attributes on another.

I have this method which is called inside the onChanged event of the parent. By parent I mean what to filter the child by i.e

- Parent = Department Multiselect
- Child = Staff Multiselect.

The child element has a data attribute of `data-departmentid`.

```
function cascadeMultiselect(control, targetControl, key) {
         this.control = control;
         this.targetControl = targetControl;
         this.key = key;
         this.toHide = [];
         this.toShow =[];
         //Get controls selectedIds
         this.selectedIds = function() {
             var selected = [];
             _.each($(this.control + " option:selected"), function(c) {
                 selected.push($(c).val());
             });
             return selected;
         };

         //Now filter 
         this.filter = function() {

             //Get target control attribute values
             _.each($(targetControl + " option"), function(tc) {
                 //Use the val as an identifier
                 var val = $(tc).val();
                 var data = $(tc).attr("data-" + key);
                 data = data.split(",");

                 var isMatch = anyMatchInArray(data, this.selectedIds());

                 if(!isMatch){
                   $(tc).hide();
                 }
             });
         }

          this.filter();

          $(targetControl).multiselect('rebuild');           
     }
```

It's being called like so:

```
 onChange: function() {
             cascadeMultiselect('#departmentlist', '#stafflist', "DepartmentID");
         }
```

The problem is I can't hide the elements. The filter works just fine, I've tried:

`$(tc).hide(); // tc = targetControl option`

I've also tried to refresh instead of rebuild.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it seems the only way to do this was to store the values of the multiselect, and then remove / add the relevant values.

I decided to use a rudimentary Cache class:

```
 var Cache = (function () {
         this.all = [];
        function Cache(control) {
            this.control = control;
         }

        Cache.prototype.getAll = function () {
            return this.all;
        };

        Cache.prototype.setAll = function (all) {
            this.all = all;
        };
        return Cache;
    })();
```

Function now looks like:

```
function cascadeMultiselect(control, targetControl, key, cache) {
         this.control = control;
         this.targetControl = targetControl;
         this.key = key;
         this.toHide = [];
         this.toShow =[];
        //To reset the multiselect
         this.reset = function(){
             $(targetControl).html('');
             $(targetControl).multiselect('dataprovider', cache.all)
         }

         //Get controls selectedIds
         this.selectedIds = function() {
             var selected = [];
             _.each($(this.control + " option:selected"), function(c) {
                 selected.push($(c).val());
             });
             return selected;
         };


         //Now filter 
         this.filter = function() {

             //Get target control attribute values
             _.each($(targetControl + " option"), function(tc) {
                 //Use the val as an identifier
                 var val = $(tc).val();
                 var data = $(tc).attr("data-" + key);
                 data = data.split(",");

                 var isMatch = anyMatchInArray(data, this.selectedIds());
                 console.log($(tc));
                 if(!isMatch){
                   $(tc).remove();
                 }
             });

         }
         //If nothing selected then reset the multiselect
           if(this.selectedIds().length == 0){
                 this.reset();
                 return;
             }else{
                 this.filter();
             }

         $(targetControl).multiselect('rebuild');

     }
```

When I first populate the multiselect with the dataprovider I add the data to the cache:

```
 if(cache != null){
             cache.setAll(this.dataToAdd);
         }
```